# parameters in service route

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, webhttpbinding, wcf-routing

Working on a WCF webhttp project and had a question on parameters in route composition.

I have two services - Project service (that allows an user to add and view projects) and an Item service that allows the users to view items inside the project. There can be multiple items in a single project.

I would like to have urls of the form

`localhost//projects//addproject`

`localhost//projects//{projectid}//item//additem`

`localhost//projects//{projectid}//item//getitem//{itemid}`

I have twoservices ItemService and ProjectService. 
Itemservice has the methods additem and getitem 
Projectservice has the methods addproject

How do I declare these services in my global routes? I tried

`RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("projects/{projectid}/item", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ItemService)));`
This gives me an error

**I can add all the code to ProjectService but I for maintainability of code I would like to have both ProjectService and ItemService**

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion:

- you can create a controller called, say: "ProjectController".
- add methods to it, that will call your service(s), say:

  - a. AddProject()
  - b. AddItem(int projectID)
  - c. GetItem(int projectID, int ItemID)

and you can call them almost the way you want:

localhost//project//AddProject

localhost//project//AddItem//{projectid}

localhost//project//GetItem//{projectid}//{itemid}